# What kind of prepaid iPhone can I use in Europe?

Tags: iphone

What kind of prepaid iPhone can I use in Europe and the US?

Comment: For people to provide a good answer, they would want to have more information - where you plan to buy the phone from, where you plan to travel, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Apple lists all current iPhone models at:

- http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3939

You'll need to determine which carrier you like in the US and Europe and see if the phone you want speaks GSM/CDMA for basic service like calls and SMS. Visual Voicemail will work on most carriers that sell iPhones, and LTE coverage and other higher speed data varies widely. See http://www.apple.com/iphone/LTE for the bands that certain countries use as well as details of which models work in which bands.